# Checking argument to avoid try..catch block ( ? )

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote this method in the .svc file

```
 public SomeDTO Method1( byte[] bitmapAsByteArr, DTO1 dto1, DTO2 dto2 )
    {
        if( bitmapAsByteArr!= null && bitmapAsByteArr.Length > 0 && dto1!= null && dto2 != null )
        {
            return new SomeDTO(bitmapAsByteArr,dto1,dto2,1,2,3,4);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
```

I was wander if this way is better them make the body of this method in try..catch block. 
What is better in this case ?

Comment: You shouldn't _return_ exceptions, you should **throw** them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you are using here is wrong in that it returns an exception instead of throwing it. I think that is a error in the question, otherwise your `SomeDTO` object would have to be somehow connected with the `ArgumentNullException` class, and that's plain wrong.

What you can do is:
- Your solution, where we check all the arguments for validity, and then do the work

```
if (are_all_arguments_ok)
{
   //procedure code, possibly hundreds of lines
}
else
{
   throw new SingleExceptionForAnyParameterIssues();
}
```

- Embed the code in a `try..catch`, like

```
try
{
   //procedure code, possibly hundreds of lines
}
catch
{
   //not really sure what we caught here
   //could be a parameter problem, could be a code problem
   throw new SingleExceptionForAnyParameterIssues();
}
```

- check the parameters at the head of the method

```
if (param1_is_null)
{
   throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
}
if (param1_is_invalid)
{
   throw new ArgumentException("bad, bad param1","param1");
}
// other parameters are checked here

//procedure code, possibly hundreds of lines
```

I (obviuosly) prefere the third method because:

- It gives a clear separation of code that checks for parameter validity, and code that does the actual work
- It enables more fine grained checks instead of a single check that basically tells me that something is wrong without specifying what
- It's at the beginning of a method, and can be hidden in a region, so I don't need to focus on it when I review the corectness of the method proper code.
- It's easy to add or change the throws to Asserts, logging statement or whatever is actually needed

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how likely it is that the arguments will be invalid. Are invalid arguments **exceptional** or **expected**.

A `try...catch` block will result in cleaner code and faster execution for the normal case, but the error case will execute more slowly.

So if this method gets called many times with invalid data this will be a potential slow point in your application and having code in the form you have will be slightly more efficient.

Comment: I see what you try to say - but if im using the try..catch block => the checking of the parameters need to be in the next level - and throwing exception need to be in the method 'Method1'

Comment: @Yanshof - technically, but an alternative is to just let the code fail - so rather than checking for a null and throwing `ArgumentNullException` say - you let the dereference fail and trap that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Code Cotracts](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/11/07/clr-4.0-code-contracts.aspx) if you are using .NET 4.0.